# Overloading operator<< twice in same class for different member variables

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Sorry if this question has been asked before, but I'm struggling with overloading the `<<` operator to stream different data into multiple files.

I have a `Player` class, which has the following attributes:

```
char* name;
char* password;
int hScore;
int totalGames;
int totalScore;
int avgScore;
```

I want to overload the `<<` operator twice: one to stream the `name`, `password` and `hScore` to a `"Players.txt"` file, and a second overload to stream the `totalGames`, `totalScore` and `avgScore` to a different `.txt` file which is based off each player's name, e.g. `"Player1.txt"`.

Here's what my operator looks like in the `Player` class:

```
friend ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Player& player)
{
    os << player.name << "\n" << player.encryptPassword((player.password), 3) << "\n" << player.hScore << "\n";
    return os;
}
```

And here's where I am calling it, from a `PlayerLibrary` class which contains a vector of `Players`:

```
ofstream out("Yahtzee.txt");
if (out.is_open())
{
    for_each(playerList.begin(), playerList.end(), [&out](Player* player) {out << (*player);});
}
else
{
    cout << "THERE WAS AN ERROR WRITING TO FILE\n";
}
```

Basically, I want to stream the other variables into another file which is named after the player name, and contains a scorecard for each game they've played. So far it looks like:

```
for (auto it = playerList.begin(); it != playerList.end(); ++it)
{
    auto position = it - playerList.begin();
    string filename(playerList[position]->getName());
    filename = filename + ".txt";
    ofstream out2(filename);

    for (int i = 0; i < playerList[position]->getNumberOfScorecards(); i++)
    {
        out2 << *playerList[position]->getScorecard(i);
    }
}
```

This only streams the scorecard and not the `totalGames`, `totalScore` and `avgScore`, like I want it to.

I have tried just moving those variables into the scorecard class, but I feel that it makes more sense to have them where they are.

I understand that I can't overload `operator<<` twice if both overloads have the same parameters, is there another way of going about this? Is there anyway perhaps in the overloaded function to use the output stream and check the name of the `.txt` file or something.

Hope the question makes sense.

Comment: Simple answer: Don't.  Create two named functions.  For example, you could have `output_player_info()` for the name and high score and `output_player_stats()` for your second "overload"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than defining an `operator<<` for `Player` itself, create a couple of utility types that refer to the `Player` and have their own `operator<<`s, let them decide which portions of the `Player` to stream, eg:

```cpp
class Player
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string password;
    int hScore;
    int totalGames;
    int totalScore;
    int avgScore;
    ...

public:
    ...

    std::string getName{} const { return name; }
    ...

    std::string EncryptPassword(int arg) const { return ...; }

    int getNumberOfScorecards() const { return ...; }
    Scorecard* getScorecard(int index) const { return ...; }

    class Info
    {
        const Player &m_player;

        void print(std::ostream &os) const {
            os << m_player.name << "\n" << m_player.encryptPassword(3) << "\n" << m_player.hScore << "\n";
        }

    public:
        Info(const Player &player) : m_player(player) {}

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Info &info)
        {
            info.print(os);
            return os;
        }
    };
    friend class Info;

    struct Stats
    {
        const Player &m_player;

        void print(std::ostream &os) const
        {
            os << m_player.totalGames << "\n" << m_player.totalScore << "\n" << m_player.avgScore << "\n";
        }

    public:
        Stats(const Player &player) : m_player(player) {}

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Stats &stats)
        {
            stats.print(os);
            return os;
        }
    };
    friend class Stats;
};
```

And then you can use them like this:

```cpp
ofstream out("Yahtzee.txt");
if (out.is_open())
{
    for(auto *player : playerList)
        out << Player::Info(*player);
}
else
{
    cout << "THERE WAS AN ERROR WRITING TO FILE\n";
}
```

```cpp
for (auto *player : playerList)
{
    ofstream out2(player->getName() + ".txt");
    out2 << Player::Stats(*player);

    for (int i = 0; i < player->getNumberOfScorecards(); ++i)
    {
        out2 << *player->getScorecard(i);
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/UV8jbG)